# which `sock_fd` to use in `setsockopt` function

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, serversocket, tcpserver

My client app uses socket as http connections, meaing one-time send,receive, and close, i considered using a single persistent connection, instead of separate connection, each time, but problem was, sometimes the server received 2 packets of 32 kiB, while a single packet of 64kiB, the other times, and somtimes even smaller size, so to compensate for the latency introduced by 3 way handshake, i wanted to enable `TCP_FASTOPEN`, and `TCP_NODELAY`,

I use `setsockopt` with both options to the client-side(`connect`ing) socket, but im confused that:

- At the **server side**, which socket to `setsockopt`, the one created with `socket` function, or the `accept`ed one, or both, for both options,
- Also, is there any solution, to the problem, of un-intentional partitioning of data packets, like 2x32k, or 4x16k, instead of 1x64k

thanking you

I read the documentation available in linux man pages, but found it confusing

Comment: Have you tried just setting these everywhere? Do these succeed or report error, and which if any?

Comment: I suggest to [edit] the question and add some background information. Explain what you want to implement and why you "*need to* enable `TCP_FASTOPEN` and `TCP_NODELAY`". The server must send and accept the cookie. Maybe see https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/

Comment: @hyde , they complete successfully, without error, but i did not find any *definitive* way, to confirm the correct working

Comment: There's no guarantee that calls to `send` and `recv` will correspond one-to-one.  Assume that they won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way.

TCP is a streaming protocol, so there's no guarantee that a single call to `send` on one side will correspond to a single call to `recv` on the other side.  You could for example call `send` once and have to call `recv` twice to get everything, or you could call `send` twice and read it all in a single `recv`.

Your protocol needs some way of knowing exactly how much data to read.  If you're actually using HTTP this is built into the protocol, i.e. read header lines separated by carriage-return/newline i.e. `\r\n` followed by a blank line followed by a body whose size is given by the `Content-Length` header.

If you're not using HTTP you could do something simple such as first sending 4 bytes for the data length followed by that many bytes of data.

In both cases, you `recv` as many bytes as you can and if the protocol indicates that there's more data then you `recv` again.  You'll also need to watch for cases where you've read a full message but there's more data in the buffer you've read in, indicating that there's another message you need to start processing.

You'll need to do all this whether or not you make a new connection each time, so you might as well just leave the connection open and not worry about the socket options.

Answer (score 1):

On the client to enable `TCP_FASTOPEN`, we can combine both connection establishment and data transmission simultaneously using `sendto()` or `sendmsg()`, as an example,

```
sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
sendto(sfd, data, data_len, MSG_FASTOPEN, 
            (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, addr_len);
    // Replaces connect() + send()/write()
// read and write further data on connected socket sfd
close(sfd);
```

However on the server side to enable TCP fastopen you need to set the option on server's listening socket as shown below,

```
sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   // Create socket
bind(sfd, ...);                          // Bind to well known address
int qlen = 5;                            // Value to be chosen by application
setsockopt(sfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN, &qlen, sizeof(qlen));
listen(sfd, ...);                        // Mark socket to receive connections
cfd = accept(sfd, NULL, 0);              // Accept connection on new socket
// read and write data on connected socket cfd
close(cfd);
```

For more details worth reading https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/

To set TCP_NODELAY nagle buffering off, set the option as below on both sockets client/server,

```
/* Disable Nagle */
int opt = 1; // 0/1: disable/enable TCP_NODELAY
setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &opt, sizeof(opt));
```